# Find first occurrence of an object with property in tree-like structure

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

I have a structure like this:

```
[{
  description: 'Beef Stew',
  complete: false,
  tasks: [{
    description: 'Cut vegetables',
    complete: false,
    tasks: [{
      description: 'Dice carrots',
      complete: false
    }, {
      description: 'Mince Garlic',
      complete: false
    }, {
      description: 'Prepare potatoes',
      complete: false,
      tasks: [{
        description: 'Peel potatoes',
        complete: false
      }, {
        description: 'Cut potatoes',
        complete: false
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

In this case, I am looking for *the first occurance of an element with no tasks that is not complete*. In this case, that means it should be `{ description: 'Dice carrots', completed: false }`. Here is the basic of what I have written. [codepen here too](http://codepen.io/AlexFrazer/pen/NGEXKG?editors=001).

```
function next(steps) {
  return steps.reduce((r, step) => {
    return (step.tasks && step.tasks.length > 0 && !step.complete) ? next(step.tasks) : step;
  }, []);
}
```

This does get a deep step, but it ends up getting the *last* step. How can I make an algorithm that will get the first?

Comment: `completed` is always `undefined`. If you had used strict mode, you'd have gotten a reference error.

Comment: Oops sorry, editted that in (wasn't in codepen), will fix

Comment: OK, it's still a typo: the property is named `complete`, not `completed`.

Comment: You're not considering the case of an element with tasks that is complete.

Comment: Do you intentionally pass `steps` as the initial value?

Comment: if a parent is marked complete, all of its children will have to be complete, if that's what you mean

Comment: No, I mean that you always just return the current `step` as soon as it is completed or has no tasks. You never consider the previous `r`esult.

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but when I do not provide an initial value, it only returns the original value

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

The mozilla site provides a polyfill implementation of this.

Applying it to your problem:

```
var matchingStep = steps.find(function(step) {
    return !(step.tasks.find(function(task) { return !(task.complete); });
});
```

Comment: That's not recursive?

Comment: @Bergi - Ah, I see your point. I didn't realize there was an arbitrary number of levels in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

I got a pretty good solution in my `Steps` class, for if anyone is looking for the answer in the future.

```
class Steps {
  constructor(steps) {
    this.steps = steps;
    this.current = steps;
  }
  next(steps=this.steps) {
    for(let step of steps) {
      if (step.tasks instanceof Array && !step.complete) {
        return this.next(step.tasks);
      }
      return this.current = step;
    }
  }
}
```

This allows me to advance the step forward recursively.